# AngularJS - display decrypted values using ngModel in inputs

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have an array of objects with encrypted values:

```
// the values are encrypted
$scope.fruits = [
    [0]: {'name':'as987s=', 'size':'Hjh6Gj0'},
    [1]: {'name':'3fss87s=', 'size':'kooi9huy8g'},
    [2]: {'name':'asdd21s=', 'size':'juHg7g'},  
];

// returns an encrypted data
$scope.decryptData = function(param) {
    return decrypt(param);
};
```

How can I display the decrypted values in a textbox?

I tried something like this in my view:

```
<div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
    {{ decryptData(fruit.name) }}
    <input type="text" ng-model="fruit.size" />
</div>
```

It works right on the label but how can I do the same thing for the text input?

Comment: So that when user enters "apple", you can match it to `fruits[0]`? Then you will have to add an `encrypt()` function to encrypt the result before comparison, or decrypt all `frunts` and match it with user input. The first have security issue and the second is not performant.

Comment: @leesei I have an encrypt() function in my original codes. I tried using decrypt/encrypt all function but I have to use the function everytime a change occured, and it will result in a slow app

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paila/gcxq5Ly6/1/)

Create a directive lets say decryptInfo and use it on input.

```
myApp.directive('decryptInfo', ['decryptService', function(decryptSvc){
   return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {   
         ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
         return decryptSvc.decrypt(data); //decrypted
        });
      }
   };
 }]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
    {{ decryptData(fruit.name) }}
    <input type="text" ng-model="fruit.size" decrypt-info />
</div>
```

Comment: It works and it answers my question but it doesnt fit to my real problem, whenever i edit the textbox, its model value also changes into decrypted form. I need to keep values in the model encrypted

Comment: Here is the link to updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paila/gcxq5Ly6/3/)
It shows both the original and decrypted values. Try interchanging the size values and you would see the decrypted values showing up on the disabled text boxes.

Comment: If it answers your question can you mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: I am having a problem using this because I'm using a service that I just downloaded